# ASP.net list of dropdownlists - similar to Access continuous form

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, repeater, selectedindexchanged

What I'm looking for is a way to mimic the MS-Access style continuous form within asp.net.  In one particular case, I want a control, bound to a datasource which returns a dropdownlist for each row, bound to the value within the datasource.  Any change to any of the dropdownlists' would perform an update to the database instantly.

I have got halfway to achieving this using a repeater control, with the DropDownList.SelectedValue assigned within the Repeater.ItemDataBound event.

But now, supposing I add an OnSelectedIndexChanged event to the DropDownList - how would I then query the repeater to know which row I was on (to get the primary key value, for example)

I'm not sure this can be done easily.. so the question is what should I really be doing?  I don't want to use a GridView that requires me to select a row to edit.. I just want to have the dropdownlists autopostback for any updates.

Hope that's clear?!

Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For examples sake, lets say we are binding to a custom class called `Record`

```
public class Record
{
    public int Id;
    public string Value;
}
```

If you put custom logic on the Repeater.OnItemCreated event you can attach the primary key to the id of the drop down list

```
protected void Repeater_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        return;

    var dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as Record;
    if (dataItem == null) return;

    var dropdown = e.Item.FindControl("myDropDown") as DropDownList;
    if (dropdown == null) return;

    dropdown.ID = dropdown.ID + dataItem.Id;
}
```

Then on the SelectedIndexChange, you can pull the id off of the dropdown that fired the event.

```
protected void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dropdown = sender as DropDownList;
    if (dropdown == null) return;

    var stringId = dropdown.ID.Replace("myDropDown", "");
    int id;
    if (Int32.TryParse(stringId, out id))
    {
        updateRecord(id, dropdown.SelectedValue);
    }
}
```

It's very much an ugly hack, but it should allow you to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks NerdFury - Looks like it might be the best option for me at the moment, although I'll have to work around some databinding issues..

Comment: Further to this, I couldn't find a way of getting the ID from the repeater's datasource until the itemdatabound event, and in there (rather than itemcreated) I couldn't alter the dropdownlists' ID! So going down Wyatt's route now of a custom control...

Comment: There is no reason that you shouldn't be able to change the id of your dropdown box in the ItemDataBound event handler.  What are you seeing happen that makes you believe that?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to tackle this would be to mimic the Access continuous form ASP.NET style. Which would be to make a UserControl to handle the row-level UI, then put said UserControl in a repeater.